# Hay alguna forma de exportar un modelo en invission?

Tags: html

Tengo varios mockups y ya los tengo con comandos mas no he podido encontrar la forma de crear un ejecutable o algo parecido para que yo pueda correrlo sin necesidad de la pagina web.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Necesitamos más info, más intentos, código o algo :(

Comment: Hay varias herramientas para crear tu modelo, lo que puedes hacer es crearlas en ellos y pasarlas como imagenes a invission donde le puedes dar interactividad que quieres. Una de estas herramientas puede ser Balsamiq Mockups-